# How to set up HTTP authentication to Munin?

Tags: authentication, munin

Today I installed and configured Munin on my server. I didn't like how it shows all those graphs without having any login system nor authentication. Is there a way to set up an authentication to Munin?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to set up [basic authentication](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth) using Apache:

```
<Directory "/path/to/munin">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Required"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/passwd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Then you can manage users using the `htpasswd` command:

```
$ htpasswd -c /path/to/passwd user1
```